# C++ - class member as pointer even if it could be as a value-type?

Tags: c++

When using forward declarations, class members of those types need to be pointers. What do you think of declaring all class members as pointers, even if the headers have been included for those classes in the header file? This seems nicely consistent, not mixed up.

Comment: Note that dynamically creating the objects has a performance cost. Small objects, such as struct 2 ints, it's best to keep by value.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bad idea. Pointers introduce a level of indirection that makes things cumbersome, unsafe (at least if you're not using smart pointers) and is harmful to performance.

Generally, you should properly include the headers so you don't run into this problem, unless there's some other reason why you need to use pointers anyway (in the case of mutual dependency, there is this need, so there it's unavoidable to use them as members and thus obviously "ok").

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have a class A, like this:

```
class    A
{
    public:
        B      my_b_member;
};
```

that needs this class B:

```
class    B
{
    public:
        int    my_integer;
};
```

Of course, the class A will need the entire definition of B, at least the part that describes B's constructor. Why ? When you'll declare your A class, one of it's member (which is B) will be instantiated as well, using its default constructor(with no argument).
So every class, or file in your project that will need an A class, will also have to include the B class definition before.

The big advantage of having a class A like this instead:

```
class    A
{
    public:
        B*      my_b_member;
};
```

is that you will only need to declare that a **B class** exists, with :

`class    B;`

before A's definition.

The only file that will need B's entire definition is the file which will contain the B's class instantiation, for example:

```
int main(void)
{
       A    a;

       a.my_b_member = new B;
       return 0;
}
```

So it depends on your project, what you are trying to achieve, etc etc.
I wouldn't say every class members **have** to be pointers, because having to instantiate each member your class contains by allocating them means that these members will be allocated on the heap, instead of the stack. In some cases you wouldn't want this to happen:

When you are manipulating network chunks, sending pointers is just impossible.